# Redirecionar site https para http

Tags: php, html, apache

Atualmente tenho um site onde utiliza um certificado SSL, como o certificado expirou e é preciso renová-lo, ocorre o erro de SSL em qualquer navegador impossibilitando as visitas dos usuários.

Gostaria de redirecionar o tráfego `https://` para o padrão `http://` utilizando o `.htaccess`.

Comment: Tente com [esta regra](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7448560/), certificar-se de que `mod_rewrite` está habilitado.

Comment: Lembrando que de qualquer forma, vai haver um erro inicial, pois a negociação do SSL (a conexão segura do https) vai ocorrer antes da requisição HTTP em si, portanto, antes do redirecionamento. É por este motivo que usualmente cada site com SSL precisa de um IP separado para cada domínio, enquanto o método HTTP 426 não for coisa comum nas hospedagens. (esse número eu decorei, me lembra de LV-426 :P )

Comment: Normalmente as hospedagens que são compartilhadas utilizam ssl compartilhados, pois sai bem mais em conta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aqui está em PHP como você deseja: ( resposta editada por @Bacco)

```
<?php
function ForceHTTP() {
    if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") {
        $url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
        $new_url = "http://" . $url . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        header("Location: $new_url");
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Não esqueça de "chamar" a função:

```
<?php ForceHTTP(); ?>
```

Ou com `.htaccess` para abrir sempre em `HTTP://`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Ou com `.htaccess` para abrir sempre em `HTTPS://` (que é como eu utilizo em meu site):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Resposta atualizada @Bacco

Comment: Ok, obrigado. hehehe' acabou me ajudando também.

Comment: bem, era isto onde estava minha dúvida, show!

Answer (score 6):

Experimenta assim, penso que resolve o teu problema. Adiciona estas linhas ao teu .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Oi, Miguel, bemvindo ao [pt.so]. O legal é explicar *porquê* sua solução funciona e *como* funciona. Confira o guia [answer].

Comment: Obrigado @Miguel, resolver meu problema!