# Redirecionar HTTPS para HTTP usando .htaccess

Tags: apache

Sistema operacional: ubuntu 14.
Servidor web: apache2.

Amigos, ja pesquisei sobre isso e nao consigo redirecionar a url, que e inserida com o protocolo https, para a mesma url, so que com http.

O contrario consigo facilmente utilizando o .htaccess (http para https).

Sei que, por padrao, o .htaccess tem seu funcionamento desabilitado no Ubuntu14 + apache2. Ja o habilitei e ja esta funcionando corretamente.

Meu certificado e autoassinado. Meus testes (https-> http) sao feitos com o SSL ativo ou desativado. Da no mesmo: se ativado, o browser mostra a tela de certificado invalido; se desativado, o browser nao consegue estabelecer a conexao com o servidor web;a url, nos dois casos, permanece no https depois de inserida.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15514/redirecionar-site-https-para-http?rq=1?

Comment: Obrigado pela indicacao da pagina, mas ja a tinha visto mais cedo. A insercao do codigo mostrado no .htaccess nao funcionou. Creio que meu problema nao esteja no .htaccess, ja que consigo de http para https com sucesso.

Answer (score 1):

Nos sites em que eu quero forçar o usuário a sempre acessar a versão HTTP ao invés da HTTPS, fazemos assim:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName site.com.br
    Redirect permanent / http://site.com.br/
</VirtualHost>
```

Entretanto, faço essa alteração na configuração do virtual host, e não no `.htaccess`. Mas creio que para o `.htaccess` seja a mesma regra.

Comment: Rodrigo, tentei acrescentar o [redirect permanent] em 2 arquivos que sao trazidos no meu ubuntu14: 000-default.conf  e default-ssl.conf. Eles trazem configuracoes para o host virtual. Mas ainda nao consegui. Obrigado pela ajuda.